# Missing PythonConsoleApp template

Tags: python, visual-studio

I want to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-01-create-project?view=vs-2022#step-1-create-a-new-python-project) but the PythonConsoleApp template is missing.
I am running VS2022 17.2.5

I have installed the Python WorkLoad. What do I need to do to get the template?

[Update]

After looking at the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-templates-not-showing-up-even-after-instal/1220481) Mateo gave I tried running VS as admin to install the work load but it did not help.

At the c:\ dos prompt I ran

```
dir pythonconsoleapp*.* /s
```

I see

```
PythonConsoleApp.vstemplate
```

in folder

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Python\ConsoleAppProject
```

[image: Location]

In VS Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Locations I see I have

[image: Project Locations setup]

Looking at the ProjectTemplates folder I have no Python folder

[image: sub folders]

So I copied the Python subfolder to the ProjectTemplates folder

[image: copied subfolder]

However I still do not get the template as an option.

I tried uninstalling VS via Programs and Features -> Visual studio installer. Then installed Visual Studio Professional again from the download link. But no joy.

Comment: Did you install the Python workload, as it says in the "Prerequisites" section?

Comment: You have `12.9k` rep(meaning experienced), still your way of asking question is like a noob

Comment: As I mentioned, I have installed the Python workload. @HimanshuPoddar can you suggest an improvement?

Comment: It seems this problem is solved by copyting the templates from another installation that didn't fail, check this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-templates-not-showing-up-even-after-instal/1220481

Comment: Thank you. I did not think my installation failed. Checking it out :-)

Comment: It can happen that the installation works but that there was an error while copying (or decompressing) the project templates, VS is somewhat famous for a rather convoluted/unreliable installer.

Comment: Thanks @MateoTorres. However uninstall and re-install did not help either.

Comment: In the thread I linked to you, it also did not work, what worked in the end was manually copying the project templates from an intallation in which that step did not fail.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar one can get xp-points for many reasons, no need to blame someone for a question.

Comment: @David when I commented, the question did not have any details and it seemed like a noob was asking questions. Also the OP has answered and asked enough question, so it's not just about reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7087)

> The console app is now called "Python Application"

Answer (score 1):

[In the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2022#user-templates) it's explained:

> If you add a compressed (.zip) file that includes a .vstemplate file to the user template directory, the template appears in the new project and new item dialog boxes.

Comment: I tried zipping up the folder and placing it in the ProjectTemplates folder but it made no difference.

Comment: I'm using the free version and there it never seems to be implemented at all, so I can't verify it, sorry